# building dynamic rules for jquery validate from php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am building a form (userModify) with all the attributes needed from the array $userFields.  I want to be able to use jquery validate to check data before it gets validated server side.  I have an array of fields that were build earlier in the page.

```
 $userFields=
 array('userName'=>array('type'=>'field','required'=>NULL,'options'=>NULL),
       'password' => array('type'=> 'field','required'=>NULL,'options'=>NULL),
       'lastName' =>array('type'=>'text','maxSize'=>'32','required'=>'*','options'=>NULL),
       'firstName'=>array('type'=>'text','maxSize'=>'32','required'=>'*','options'=>NULL),
       'phoneNumber'=>array('type'=>'select','maxSize'=>NULL,'required'=>NULL,'options'=>$numbers),
       'extension' =>array('type'=>'text','maxSize'=>'8','required'=>'*','options'=>NULL));
```

the validate script:

```
 $( "#userModify" ).validate({
   rules: {
       phoneNumber: {
            required: true
       }
  }
 });
```

my question is how can i get the field rules into the jquery validate structure dynamically.  Looking at the array, so in this example I would build rules for lastName,firstName, and extension.  I don't want to add the field rules statically because the array could be any number of different fields, and the validate structure would contain tons of rules.

I thought about making an ajax call to another file to get the array originally, then break apart the result of the ajax call, is that a good idea?

i know this code is clearly wrong, but i wrote this below to try to describe what i am trying to do.

```
  $( "#userModify" ).validate({
     rules: {
       <?php
       foreach ($userFields as $k => $v)
       {
          if ($v['required'] == "*")
          {
             //add jquery rule
          }
        }
        ?>
       });
```

are there any other methods I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, you just transfer the data to the javascript and let it create the rules:

```
var form = <?php echo json_encode($userFields); ?>;
var rules = {}, i;

for (name in form) {
    if (form[name].required === '*') {
        rules[name].required = true;
    }
}

$( "#userModify" ).validate({ rules: rules });
```